# Is it possible to make a disk-to-disk clone via USB?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, sata, cloning

I have an internal laptop HDD which I wish to copy to another SATA HDD.

There is no spare storage for storing an image, so I wish to make a direct disk-to-disk clone.
I have connected the destination HDD via a USB-SATA powered adapter. CloneZilla does not seem to support this during disk-to-disk mode, as it's only looking at SATA connections and doesn't mount USB devices at that point.

Are there alternatives? Or is there another way to do it with CloneZilla?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible using Clonezilla.  The issue might be in how you load Clonezilla.

Try [Parted Magic](http://partedmagic.com/doku.php)'s version:

- Download & burn the ISO
- boot the CD
- Connect the drive to the USB/SATA connector
- **THEN** start the version of Clonezilla that is included with Parted Magic

Answer (score 1):

`dd` in Linux will do it; you just need to know what the device path is

`dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdx`

... replacing `x` with the device letter in Linux. You can find this out by typing

`sudo fdisk -l`